# When did Vishnu become brother of Parvati?

Tags: vishnu, parvati

Vishnu is not biological brother of Parvati. But still he is considered has her brother. When did he become his brother ?
Is Vishnu also brother of Sati ?

Answer (score 1):

Vishnu and Parvati are brothers and sisters in terms of tattvas, Same with Brahma and Lakshmi, and Rudra and Saraswati respectively.

**Sri [Brahmanda](http://www.astrojyoti.com/brahmandapurana-3.htm) Purana** says that Mata Tripura Sundari along with her husband Bhagawan Tryambaka Bhairava Shiva creates the whole universes along with Tridevs and Tridevis as follows.:

> *A. From the left eye, which was of the nature of Soma (moon) came Brahma and Lakshmi.*
>
> *B. From the right eye, which was of the nature of Soorya (sun) came Vishnu and Parvati.*
>
> *C. From the third eye, which was of the nature of Agni (fire), came Rudra and Sarasvati.*

I hope this clarifies your queries. Prd..

Answer (score 1):

In Srimad bhagavatham the following are the slokas in which Sri Krishna speaks with Devi or yoga maya

> gaccha devi vrajaṁ bhadre
> gopa-gobhir alaṅkṛtam
> rohiṇī vasudevasya
> bhāryāste nanda-gokule
> anyāś ca kaṁsa-saṁvignā
> vivareṣu vasanti hi -- SB 10.2.7
>
> 'O Devî, so auspicious, go to Vraja beautiful with her cowherds and cows, where Rohinî and other wives of Vasudeva are living in the cowherd-community [Gokula] of Nanda in seclusion out of fear for Kamsa.
> In the womb of Devakî there is the embryo known as [Ananta-] S'esha that is a plenary expansion of Me; make a smooth transfer by motivating Him to move out of her into the womb of Rohinî.
>
> Then will I with My full potency do My share in becoming Devakî's son,
> o all-auspicious one, while you as well will appear as the daughter of
> Yas'odâ, the wife of Nanda.
>
> The people will with incense worship you as the fulfillment of all
> their desires in different forms of sacrifice, because you for all
> that one may desire are the one capable of bestowing the blessings.
>
> Depending on the place on earth [**] will you be given different names
> like Durgâ, Bhadrakâli, Vijayâ, Vaishnavî and Kumudâ, Candikâ,
> Krishnâ, Mâdhavî, Kanyakâ [or Kanyâ-kumârî], and Mâyâ, Nârâyanî,
> Îs'ânî, S'âradâ and also Ambikâ.

[Srimad bhagavatham](https://www.srimadbhagavatam.org/canto10/chapter2.html#Text_7)

As they are both born or transferred between wombs of same mothers they became brother and sister. Also they are Narayana and Narayani.